# Round up number with decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following output numbers from prices of products:

```
<span class="amount">77.08</span>
<span class="amount">18.18</span>
<span class="amount">20.25</span>
```

I want to round them up always no matter what price is, so the result in this case would be:

```
<span class="amount">78</span>
<span class="amount">19</span>
<span class="amount">21</span>
```

I tried with this code but it just removes the whole number:

```
jQuery('.amount').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).html(Math.round(parseFloat(jQuery(this).html())));
});
```

Any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Math.ceil()` instead of `Math.round()`:

```
jQuery(this).html(Math.ceil(parseFloat(jQuery(this).html())));
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dv5wkggw/)

Also note that you can provide a function to `html()` to tidy the code a little:

```
$(this).html(function(i, html) {
    return Math.ceil(parseFloat(html)));
});
```

Comment: is it possible to use this if the `span` has the currency inside like this: `<span class="amount">€77.08</span>`?

Comment: No, as in that case `parseFloat()` would return `NaN`. If there is a currency symbol preceding the value you would need to remove it, try `parseFloat(html.substr(1));`